# Python: subprocess.Popen().communicate() prints output of an SSH command to stdout instead of returning the output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, shlex

Here's a copy of my python terminal:

```
>> import subprocess
>> import shlex
>> host = 'myhost'
>> subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('ssh -o LogLevel=error -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o BatchMode=yes %s "hostname --short"' % (host))).communicate()
myhost
(None, None)
```

I would expect the output to be `('myhost', None)`. Why isn't the output being stored in the return tuple for communicate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `subprocess.Popen` call a `stdout` argument. For example:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
(b'Vagrantfile\n', None)
>>>
```

The output of the command then appears where you expect it.